# Как разделить двоичный файл на несколько частей с фиксированным размером

Tags: linux, bash

Есть двоичный файл, его нужно разрезать на три части разного размера, чтобы заменить одну из них, и потом снова склеить. Какой командой это делается?

Comment: `$ man split` + `$ man cat`. ну или `$ man dd` для совсем уж тонких манипуляций.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, есть файл `input.bin`, его нужно разделить на три части: 10 байт, 11 байт и оставшееся число байт. Воспользуемся командой [`dd`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=dd&category=1&russian=0):

```bash
dd iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes if=input.bin of=01.bin skip=0 count=10
dd iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes if=input.bin of=02.bin skip=10 count=11
dd iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes if=input.bin of=03.bin skip=21
```

После всех необходимых манипуляций с частями, соединяем их обратно с помощью [`cat`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=cat&category=1&russian=0):

```bash
cat 01.bin 02.bin 03.bin > output.bin
```

В команде `dd` я использовал флаги `skip_bytes` и `count_bytes` для того, чтобы в параметрах `skip` и `count` указывать размер в байтах. Это позволяет не задавать параметр `bs=` и эффективно копировать бинарный файл, так как при чтении будет использоваться стандартный размер буфера.